# How to control the name of backups from Time Machine

Tags: backup, external-hdd

Time Machine on my MacBook Pro names backup directories with paths like this by default:

```
Volumes/My Backup Drive/Backups.backupdb/User’s MacBook Pro/2018-04-10-224116
```

I want to tell it a folder name to use so the results do not have the apostrophe in them. This character creates problems (or at least adds complexity) when working with normal Unix commands. How do I tell Time Machine to use the folder naming conventions I want on its backups?

Comment: Take a look here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177648/how-to-give-custom-name-to-time-machine-backup .It seems that is not possible.

Comment: @thrig I think you should post your comment as an answer except you need to include that you have to look under "sharing" to find the field to change the computer name (within system preferences).  Your answer seems useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

This name is taken from the computer's name that can be set in the "Sharing" preference pane under the "System Preferences" application; changing it though will create a new backup tree name, so the name probably should not be changed without also renaming the backup tree first (while backups are not running!) or accepting that a new backup tree will be created for the new name (which may make older backups more difficult to find). A changed name may also throw off network shares if you are using the system as a file server for other hosts.

For other options, see the `tmutil(8)` command line utility.

Comment: `tmutil(8)` - how do you use this?  type it literally at terminal and you get a syntax error.

Comment: `tmutil(8)` means you should either run `tmutil` or possibly first instead `man 8 tmutil`